# changing the dropdown arrow on select field on contact form 7

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css, contact-form

I've run into a slight hickup trying to implement some jquery on my wordpress plugin contact form 7

Its the contact form in the sidebar here goo.gl/BIWD3

http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/

I'm trying to style the select field and change the dropdown arrow to make it orange, but can't seem to manage it.

Any direction on this problem would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You haven't loaded the jqTransform script and you also need to add the script using enqueue_script & add class to your contact form 7 wpcf7_form_class_attr using a filter and add jQuery function inside your script as well to activate the function.

Comment: it seems you are using this image..
http://www.dfc-e.com/sites/theme/jscripts/vendors/jqtransformplugin/img/select_right.gif
 can't you just change it?